# is it possible that a function has some value of derivative at a point even if it isn't differentiable at that point?

Tags: derivatives

Say the value of $dy/dx$ for a function $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ was turning out to be some finite value $A$, is it still possible that the function is non-differentiable at $x=a$.

If I'm getting a finite value of derivative for a function at a point, can I be sure about that the function is differentiable at that point? or is it like getting a finite value at a point doesn't guarantee that the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: Your question sounds like “If $f'(a)$ exists, can I be sure that $f$ is differentiable at $a$?” Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe do you have a precise example in mind ? The question doesn't really make sens to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, except for exists I mean "is some finite value"

Comment: Since, by definition, $f'(a)$ is the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ when this limit exists *and it is a real number*, your question makes no sense to.

Comment: When you say "you are getting", you are getting a value *how*? I think you are confusing what it means to be not differentiable - for example, $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ even though we "get" two values $1,-1$ - it's not differentiable precisely because we are getting multiple values which don't agree with each other

Comment: @FShrike My question stems from a function which was similar to |x|, i.e. it had a kink. Taking the example of |x|, I thought that we can take a value of x just after x=0 and just before x=0, and then take a difference of these quantities and then divide by the differential distance of these points, to get a finite value. So that is what I meant, that even though |x| is not differentiable at x=0 I can get a value of dy/dx at x=0

Comment: So, no. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative).

Comment: You are getting a value, not of $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x$, but rather of some $\Delta y/\Delta x$ approximation. Furthermore, I think from your description that you are in fact taking a "symmetric derivative" which is **not** the same as a derivative - the derivative centres itself at $x_0$ and considers perturbations $x_0+h$; the symmetric  derivative considers $x_0-h,x_0+h$ and this is not the same thing - e.g., $|x|$ is symmetrically differentiable everywhere but not differentiable everywhere

Comment: @HarshitRajput " that even though |x| is not differentiable at x=0 I can get a value of dy/dx at x=0 " No this is not true,you cannot get a value of dy/dx at x=0 as Right hand derivative will be 1 where as Left Hand Derivative to be -1.

Comment: Understood, that value that I'm talking about is just a $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ not dy/dx. Thank You All.